# MySQL query not using index

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have a MySQL query that is running very slowly because it's not using an index on the join key. What is wrong with my table structure that the optimizer is not using the index?

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT *  FROM indicator_performance_averages
LEFT OUTER JOIN `prof` ON (`prof`.`symbol` = indicator_performance_averages.`symbol`) 
WHERE (indicator_performance_averages.`symbol` = 'ZCN13');
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                          | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | indicator_performance_averages | const | idx_symbol    | idx_symbol | 98      | const |       1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | prof                           | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  | 1102075 |       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------+

mysql> DESCRIBE indicator_performance_averages;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| symbol             | varchar(32)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| date               | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_update        | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE prof;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| symbol        | varchar(32)         | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| name          | varchar(128)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| lastupdate    | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

EDIT: Adding SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `indicator_performance_averages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `symbol` varchar(32) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date` date default NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_symbol` (`symbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6719 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `prof` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `symbol` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `lastupdate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_symbol` (`symbol`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37736071 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: MySQl is using the `indicator_performance_averages.idx_symbol` index on the JOIN. It will only use one index on a JOIN because it already knows the value on the other side.

Comment: Using what character sets are the respective `symbol` columns encoded?

Comment: We would expect that unique key on `prof.symbol` to show up in the possible_keys column in the plan. There's not enough information here to debug the problem. I think we'd need the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both of the tables, in order to identify the problem. Since this is a VARCHAR column, the likely suspects are a difference in characterset or collation.

Comment: @mike-w, I don't understand how that helps. Why can't it use the index to find the value in the prof table?

Comment: @eggyal You had me excited there for a minute because one was utf8 and the other was latin1, but I still have the same problem when I switch to latin1.

Comment: And what encoding does your database connection use?

Comment: @spencer7593 you're right, of course. Sorry about that, I've added the show create tables.

Comment: @spencer7593 And yes I know that unique key on 'id' is unnecessary... not my table...

Comment: @eggyal looks like it's utf8, but I'd be very surprised if that affected a join between 2 tables...

Comment: @spencer7593 I meant they added a unique index on it even though it's also the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `character set utf8` on indicator_performance_averages.symbol does not match the `character set latin1` on prof.symbol.

This prevents MySQL from using an index on prof.symbol.

To get the index available to the query plan, you'd need to convert the characterset in the predicate to match the datatype of the column. Try changing the join predicate to this...

```
ON (`prof`.`symbol` = CONVERT(indicator_performance_averages.`symbol` USING latin1)
```

(I think that's the right syntax. What we're trying to make happen is for MySQL to take the utf8 value from the ipa table, and convert that to latin1, before it does the lookup to the prof table. A CAST() function can be used as well.)

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted the character set for the table using navicat, but didn't realize that that wouldn't adjust the individual fields.

Comment: @Colin M: I hesitated recommending you change the characterset of the column, because there might be a reason it's set that way. Yes, the characterset for the table is the default that will be used when new columns are added. The characterset is really specified at a per column level when the column is created. But it's just more convenient not to have to specify it on every character column, and let the column "inherit" the setting from table, which the table inherits from the database at creation time, which the database inherits from the instance at creation time.